# Migration from jetty 7.6 to 9.4.7

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I was using jetty 7.6.5 version in one of my project and now we want to upgrade to jetty 9.4.7. And found that multiple class have been removed or changed in 9.4.7 version. 
*Example:*

```
httpClient.setConnectorType(HttpClient.CONNECTOR_SELECT_CHANNEL);
ExecutorThreadPool pool = new ExecutorThreadPool(execSvc);
httpClient.setThreadPool(pool); httpClient.setTimeout(1000);
```

This code does not work on jetty 9. Please help how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer your questions first:

- Connector types do not exist in the same way as it did in Jetty 7.x.  The default is NIO based.
- Executors / ThreadPools can only be set on the constructor. (Don't set small thread pools!)
- There are many flavors of timeout you can set from the HttpClient itself, do you want idle timeout? connection timeout? dns lookup timeout? etc...  Check [the javadoc](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpClient.html) for details.
- There are also per-request timeouts available.  Again, check [the javadoc](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpClient.html) for details on which kind you want.

Going from Jetty 7.6.x series to 9.4.x series is a huge jump.  You are skipping nearly 8 years of heavy development and change in your usage. (7.x is 2009 vintage to 9.4.x is new to 2017)

The techniques and mechanisms you were using in the past are likely no longer present anymore.

This is because HttpClient has been updated significantly for HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2, ALPN, Unix Socket, FCGI, WebSocket, etc.

The most significant is to treat the new HttpClient like a web browser, start it once, and leave it running, perform as many requests as you like against it.   The worst thing you can do for yourself is to start it, perform a request or two, then stop it.  This kind of usage is not supported and can lead to strange issues with memory/threading/etc.  Start it once when you first need it, don't stop/shutdown that HttpClient instance till your application stops.

Comment: Thanks Joakim for your reply, But i would like to know basically what has changed between these two version in terms of Architecture.?

Comment: This is a huge topic, not appropriate for stackoverflow. Reminder, Jetty versioning is `<servlet_support>.<major_version>.<minor_version>` you have to understand that between 7.6.x and 9.4.x you are looking at about 8 **major versions** of Jetty difference.  Which if you did a diff between you would see that nearly the entire codebase has been changed in some fashion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joakim. One more question earlier we used to call cancel() function to cancel the exchange. but now how can we achieve it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cancel on the old exchange object.  That would be a good question for the jetty issue tracker. https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/new

Comment: Hi Joakim, I am using CometD 3.1.3 jar in a project with Jetty version 9.4.7 and but i get noClassDefFoundError for org/cometd/common/JettyJSONContext$FieldJSON. I have found that since class org.eclipse.jetty.util.ajax.JSON is missing in Jetty that's why i am getting this error. Could you please let me know which the compatible version of jetty to use with CometD 3.1.3 library ?

Comment: Class `org.eclipse.jetty.util.ajax.JSON` is not missing from Jetty, it's in artifact `jetty-util-ajax`. You probably just need to add it as an explicit dependency.